# in JTable remove space between images

Tags: java, swing, jtable, graphics2d, tablecellrenderer

In the picture below you see a `JTable` with two columns.

**UPDATE

**The columns are hidden. The red behind the selected row is

background color red only for demonstration purpose**.  **

Each row have two pictures.

First picture is a png image looking like a checkbox. Followed by
a png image that the name of the friend is written onto.

The images should look like one image but there is a space.

Is is possible to remove this space?
The images does not have the space

Maybe it's not doable using `JTable`.
In that case what other swing "list" can do this.

The code that creates the table

```
        jTableSpriidFriends = new JTable();
        jTableSpriidFriends.setRowMargin(0);
        jTableSpriidFriends.setIntercellSpacing(new Dimension(0, 0));
        jTableSpriidFriends.setShowHorizontalLines(false);
        jTableSpriidFriends.setShowVerticalLines(false);
        jTableSpriidFriends.setShowGrid(false);
        m_adapterSpriidFriends = new AbstractTableModelJTableSpriidFriends();
        rendererSpriidFriends = new CellRendererJtableSpriidFriends();
        jTableSpriidFriends.setModel(m_adapterSpriidFriends);
        jTableSpriidFriends.setDefaultRenderer(ImageIcon.class,
rendererSpriidFriends );
        jTableSpriidFriends.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);
        jTableSpriidFriends.addMouseListener(this);
        jTableSpriidFriends.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(this);
        jTableSpriidFriends.setTableHeader(null);

        scrollPaneSpriidFriends = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPaneSpriidFriends.setBounds(11, 55, 176, 264);
        panelSpriid.add(scrollPaneSpriidFriends);
        scrollPaneSpriidFriends.setViewportView(jTableSpriidFriends);

    for (int i=0; i<m_adapterSpriidFriends.getColumnCount(); i++) {
        TableColumn column = jTableSpriidFriends.getColumnModel().getColumn(i);
        if (i==0) column.setPreferredWidth(50);
        if (i==1) column.setPreferredWidth(120);

    }
```

Here the DefaultTableCellRenderer

```
case 0:// type

    if(friend.selected){
       image = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource
       ("/resources/friendlist/checkbox_checked.png")).getImage();
       this.setIcon( new ImageIcon(image));
    }else{
       image = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/resources
       /friendlist/checkbox_unchecked.png")).getImage();
       this.setIcon( new ImageIcon(image));
    }

    break;
case 1:// files

    BufferedImage old = null;
    try {

         if(friend.deviceType.equals(Consts.DEVICE_TYPE_DEVICE))
        old = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource
        ("/resources/friendlist/row_with_device.png"));
          else
        old = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource
        ("/resources/friendlist/row_with_pc.png"));

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

      int w = old.getWidth();
      int h = old.getHeight();
      BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

      Graphics2D g2d = img.createGraphics();
      g2d.drawImage(old, 0, 0, null);
      g2d.setPaint(Color.WHITE);
      //g2d.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 20));

      String s = friend.name;
      FontMetrics fm = g2d.getFontMetrics();
      int x = 10 ;
      int y = 20;
      g2d.drawString(s, x, y);
      g2d.dispose();


    this.setIcon( new ImageIcon(img));
    break;              
}
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `myTable.setShowVerticalLines(false);`? Also check out `JTable.setIntercellSpacing(Dimension intercellSpacing)`.

Comment: The setShowVerticalLines was already set to false but the setIntercellSpacing i forgot. setting setIntercellSpacing(new Dimension(0, 0)); ....does not make any difference.

Comment: for better help sooner edit your question with a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), for icons you can simply to use `UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.questionIcon")`

Comment: @mKorbel I dont know what you talking about concerning "OptionPane.questionIcon". Can you clarify?

Comment: adding SSCCE thanks to @mKorbel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can just use a JList with custom renderer. The renderer would then take the spriid friend objects and construct appropriate labels using a simple JPanel with GridLayout.

Comment: Technically, no. But you can make it look like two columns in the renderer.

Comment: works nice with JList. removed the check image totaly and using two large images, one with check and one without.

Answer (score 3):

The default cell renderer extends JLabel, and uses itself as component to display the cell.
A JLabel has icon and text with a gap in between. Maybe that is the cause:

```
table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new DefaultTableCellRenderer() {

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        Component comp = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
        if (comp instanceof JLabel) {
            JLabel label = (JLabel)comp;
            label.setIconTextGap(0);
        }
        return comp;
    }

});
```

---

***Alternatively:***

```
table.setDefaultRenderer(ImageIcon.class, new DefaultTableCellRenderer() {
    {
        setIconTextGap(0);
    }
});
```

Comment: interesting will test some..My getColumnClass() in the AbstractTableModel is returning ImageIcon.class

Comment: could i return something else from the getTableCellRendererComponent and how? The method ends with this.setText(""); ...

Comment: It is good to realize, that one single component is reused for more than one cell; therefore properties as text and color are set every time again. You should do likewise, but the component is irrelevant. For the code in my answer I will give an alternative.